# Attach an object to another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Where can i find the script on c# (unity3d) to attach an object to another object when you press the mouse button?

I tried to use a lot of different scripts, but one does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
     RaycastHit hit;
     Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
     if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
         if (hit.collider == this.gameobject) // this can be checked on parent or child, your call
         this.transform.parent = yourParentObject;            
}
```

Comment: If you want to move the object to the parent location you would just add this.gameobject.transform.position = yourParentObject.transform.position